# Unable to convert degree to number in LatitudeLongitude and "City" Entity

Tags: geography, conversion, entity

I am trying to convert degree to number for some mathematical transformation. Taking London as an example, the following codes can convert the degree into a number without any problems:

Codes that give numbers `{51.5,-0.11}` and `{0.8988,-0.0019}` as output:

```
{51.5°,-0.12°} /Degree
{51.5°,-0.12°} /. GeoPosition -> Identity
```

However, I want to use London as the input. In fact, if I input

```
LatitudeLongitude[Entity["City",{"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]]
```

I can get `{51.5°,-0.12°}` without a problem.

The problem is, when I combine the two, the result fails to convert into number. It is still in degrees.

Codes that still give degree as output:

```
LatitudeLongitude[Entity["City",{"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]]/Degree
LatitudeLongitude[Entity["City",{"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]]/. GeoPosition -> Identity
```

How can I convert that into degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `LatitudeLongitude` is a `List` of `Quantity`s:

```
pos = LatitudeLongitude[Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]]

FullForm@pos
```

> `` List[Quantity[51.5`,"AngularDegrees"],Quantity[-0.1166667`,"AngularDegrees"]] ``

This would suggest to use `UnitConvert`:

```
UnitConvert[pos, "Radians"]
```

> {0.898845rad,-0.00203622rad}

which again is a `List` of `Quantity`s:

```
FullForm@%
```

> `` List[Quantity[0.8988445647770799`,"Radians"],Quantity[-0.0020362180424364686`,"Radians"]] ``

One could extract the numbers with `[[All, 1]]`. **However**, this whole line of reasoning leads to overcomplication of the procedure, as the **straighforward approach** is

```
Normal@pos
```

> {0.898845, -0.00203622}

Comment: Thanks. Done with `Normal[LatitudeLongitude [Entity["City",{"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]]]/Degree` as suggested.